# How do I get nodemailer to interpret html?

Tags: javascript, html, nodemailer

I'm using TinyMCE to save formatted text to my mongodb, then sending said text as an email.

**How it currently looks**

```
<p>Test.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>23412321 1231232</p>
```

**How I'd like it to look**

```
Test

23412321 1231232
```

I've tried to reformat how nodemailer interprets the text using below based on semi-related nodemailer docs but it's not working.

```
 const message = {
        content: event.redemption_details,
        contentType: 'text/html'
    };
```

How do I get nodemailer to properly format the text?

Comment: As per nodemailer [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/message/) there is no `content` or `contentType` properties available in configuring message. `text` is for plain text content, `html` is for html content

Comment: Thanks @Wazeed - I've continued to research and have come to a similar conclusion. Thanks for the comment.